# Subsequent object references vs. subsequent method calls

Tags: vb.net, memory-access

In my years of programming, I've been left with the impression storing a value from a method call into a variable and then repeatedly accessing that variable is a lot quicker than just having subsequent calls to the method.

For example, I have the following code that takes an `Integer` variable, appens a `String` to it, and returns the result.

My expectations were that accessing a previously declared variable multiple times would be much quicker than making subsequent calls to this method, which processes the `Integer`, however my results turn out quite the opposite.

```
100 Test, 100 Test, 100 Test, 100 Test
Stroing in variable: 0.001

100 Test, 100 Test, 100 Test, 100 Test
Calling function on each instance: 0.0005
```

So why is it that multiple calls to a function are seemingly faster than only one call to a function, then multiple memory accesses?

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim TestInteger As Integer = 100
    Dim TestString As String = ReturnString(TestInteger)
    Dim StartTime As DateTime = New DateTime()
    Dim EndTime As DateTime = New DateTime()

    StartTime = DateTime.Now
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", TestString, TestString, TestString, TestString)
    EndTime = DateTime.Now

    Console.WriteLine("Storing in variable: {0}" & Environment.NewLine, EndTime.Subtract(StartTime).TotalSeconds)

    StartTime = DateTime.Now
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", ReturnString(TestInteger), ReturnString(TestInteger), ReturnString(TestInteger), ReturnString(TestInteger))
    EndTime = DateTime.Now

    Console.WriteLine("Calling function on each instance: {0}", EndTime.Subtract(StartTime).TotalSeconds)

    Console.Read()
End Sub

Function ReturnString(ByVal Int As Integer)
    Dim MyString As String = Int.ToString

    MyString = MyString & " Test"

    Return MyString
End Function

End Module
```

Comment: I think your test is flawed starting with using a DateTime var to clock the results of just 4 operations.  After some changes, I get the function call being 3-5+ times slower .

Comment: I'm relateively new to VB.NET, so DateTime was the only method I knew of to clock time.

Comment: Still a rough test, but ~100 times slower: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9Lt2AF#